# October cms file attachment with only path?

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I'm a new in October CMS. Now i have an issue with file attachment. In Model :

```
public $attachOne = [
        'cover_image' => ['System\Models\File']
    ];
```

Now in controller :

```
$comic = Comic::with('cover_image)->find($id);
```

it return:

```
{
"id": 24,
"title": "Comic example detail",
"description": "Comic example detail",
"total_page": "14",
"cover_image": {
"id": 165,
"disk_name": "5d5a21ca68bf9280597931.png",
"file_name": "img06.png",
"file_size": 142958,
"content_type": "image/png",
"title": null,
"description": null,
"field": "cover_image",
"sort_order": 165,
"created_at": "2019-08-19 04:12:58",
"updated_at": "2019-08-19 04:15:23",
"path": "http://localhost:10080/storage/app/uploads/public/5d5/a21/ca6/5d5a21ca68bf9280597931.png",
"extension": "png"
}
}
```

I want cover_image return only some field, like below:

```
"cover_image": {
"id": 165,
"file_name": "img06.png",
"path": "http://localhost:10080/storage/app/uploads/public/5d5/a21/ca6/5d5a21ca68bf9280597931.png",
}
```

how can i do it?

Comment: Did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

use constraint eager loading

see in the doc https://octobercms.com/docs/database/relations#constraining-eager-loads

it is explained with `where` statement but you can use `select` statement and you can get only required `attributes`.

I am sure it will help you.